# Why page.$$eval is working too many times?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I want to build a simple bot with puppeteeer.
I used page.$$eval then I tried to fetch data from table(10 page) and mapped that data.

However I can fetch data very well on the other hand the code is working 10 times per page. I mean every row fetched 10 times.

Here is my code snippet:

```
const tablolariCek = async (url, sayfaSayisi) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  let page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  await page.waitForSelector('#mydata_next');
  let okulUni = [];
  for (let index = 0; index <= sayfaSayisi; index++) {
    let okullar = await page.$$eval(
      '#mydata > tbody > [role="row"]',
      (uniler) =>
        uniler.map((okul) => {
          //Here is working 10 times per page.
          let uni = {};
          uni.okulkodu = okul.querySelector('a').innerText.trim();
          const fontVeriler = okul.querySelectorAll('font');
          const strongVeriler = okul.querySelectorAll('strong');
          for (let index = 0; index < strongVeriler.length; index++) {
            if (index == 0) {
              uni.uniadi = strongVeriler[index].innerText.trim();
            } else if (index == 1) {
              uni.bolumadi = strongVeriler[index].innerText.trim();
            }
          }
          for (let index = 0; index < fontVeriler.length; index++) {
            if (index == 1) {
              uni.bolumadi += ' ' + fontVeriler[index].innerText.trim();
            } else if (index == 10) {
              uni.siralama2019 = fontVeriler[index].innerText.trim();
            } else if (index == 14) {
              uni.puan2019 = fontVeriler[index].innerText.trim();
            }
          }

          return uni;
        })
    );
    await page.click('#mydata_next');
    okullar.forEach((okul) => {
      okulUni.push(okul);
    });

  }

  browser.close();

  return okulUni;
};
```

Here it is what am I trying to fetch

```
<table id="mydata">
<tbody>
<tr role="row" class="odd">//this line
</tbody>
```

I can't find solution.

I found a solution by changing this line.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false,slowMo: 150 });
```

I think due to the speed The code can't fetch table that exactly right. Everything works fine now. Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Since `'#mydata > tbody > [role="row"]'` are returning 10 entries and you are using `.map` which will execute 10 times. Can you try replacing `'#mydata > tbody  > [role="row"]'` with just `'#mydata > tbody`? not sure if this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by changing this line.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false,slowMo: 150 });
```

I think due to the speed The code can't fetch table that exactly right. Everything works fine now. Thank you for the answers.